# Enum class' underlying type aliased to integral type (compile error)

Tags: c++, gcc, types, enums, underlyingtype

I compile this with GCC 7.2.0:

```
typedef float Signal_t;

enum class Signal_level : Signal_t {
  low = -1.0, neutral = 0.0, high = 1.0
};
```

the compiler response is:

```
error: underlying type ‘Signal_t {aka float}’ of ‘Signal_level’ must be an integral type
```

Is this behavior dictated by the standard (`-std=c++17`) or is specific to GCC? 
I'd expect GCC to recognize `Signal_t` as an integral type.

Comment: Why do you expect a float to be an integral type?

Comment: Because my personal definition of integral type diverged from reality. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use floating point as the enum underlying type sorry.

Comment: use `int` still can represent float somehow, for example, I want measure voltage, `4.2v`, then I can have define line `4200mv`

Answer (score 3):

According to [[dcl.enum]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#2.sentence-4):

> The *type-specifier-seq* of an *enum-base* shall name an integral type; any cv-qualification is ignored.

Here the *type-specifier-seq* refers to the part after `:`.

And what are integral types ([[basic.types]p7](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.fundamental-7)):

> Types bool, char, char16_­t, char32_­t, wchar_­t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types.<sup>47</sup> A synonym for integral type is integer type.

So a float is not part of the integral types, and so is not valid to use in an enum as base.